# SQL Procedure Getting Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a simple procedure in the SQL in which i need to copy data from one table and store it into the instance table. I have write this code but i am getting error. Here is my code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ShaniProc -- Always apend the schema
AS
DECLARE @Driver nvarchar(20)

DECLARE @active_surveys TABLE
    (
    active_id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ani varchar,
    callDisposition int,
    CallTypeID int,
    [DateTIme] datetime, -- [Datetime]  is a really bad idea for a column name, but 
                         -- if you want to use it, you need to enclose it in square brackets
    DbDateTime datetime,
    TalkTime int,
    DNIS varchar(32),
    Duration int,
    PerpheralID smallint,
    RecoveryKey float
    )

Insert into @active_surveys (active_id,ani,callDisposition,CallTypeID,[DateTime],DbDateTime,TalkTime,DNIS,Duration,PerpheralID,RecoveryKey ) 
-- You shouldn't use VALUES if you are doing a SELECT for inserting rows
Select t.AgentSkillTargetID,t.ANI,t.CallDisposition,t.CallTypeID,t.[DateTime],t.DbDateTime,t.TalkTime,
t.DNIS,t.Duration,t.PeripheralID,t.RecoveryKey from TCD t;

Declare @total int;
Select @total=COUNT(*) from @active_surveys;
print '>> Total Surveys: '+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),@total),'')
```

I am getting this error

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ShaniProc, Line 26
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ShaniProc, Line 28
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Comment: Don't create a temp table with an identity if you intend to not use it. I should  virtually never see a proc that uses identityinsert, this is intended for DBA use only and never should be in a procedure that anyone else will use or that will be done frequently.

Comment: Also, if you want to know how many rows were just inserted into a table that you just created, use `@@ROWCOUNT` immediately after the `INSERT` - don't do a `COUNT(*)` over the table.

Answer (score 4):

You have more than just one problem with your query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ShaniProc -- Always apend the schema
AS
DECLARE @Driver nvarchar(20)

DECLARE @active_surveys TABLE
    (
    active_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    ani varchar,
    callDisposition int,
    CallTypeID int,
    [DateTIme] datetime, -- [Datetime]  is a really bad idea for a column name, but 
                         -- if you want to use it, you need to enclose it in square brackets
    DbDateTime datetime,
    TalkTime int,
    DNIS varchar(32),
    Duration int,
    PerpheralID smallint,
    RecoveryKey float
    )


Insert into @active_surveys (active_id,ani,callDisposition,CallTypeID,[DateTime],DbDateTime,TalkTime,DNIS,Duration,PerpheralID,RecoveryKey ) 
-- You shouldn't use VALUES if you are doing a SELECT for inserting rows
Select t.AgentSkillTargetID,t.ANI,t.CallDisposition,t.CallTypeID,t.[DateTime],t.DbDateTime,t.TalkTime,
t.DNIS,t.Duration,t.PeripheralID,t.RecoveryKey from TCD t;

Declare @total int;
Select @total=COUNT(*) from @active_surveys;
print '>> Total Surveys: '+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),@total),'')
```

Also, as HLGEM points out, why creating an `IDENTITY` column on a variable table and then not use it?, what's the point?

Comment: Msg 1077, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ShaniProc, Line 22
INSERT into an identity column not allowed on table variables., I am getting this error

Comment: @Malik Then just don't create that column as an `IDENTITY`, the error is pretty clear

Comment: I have removed the Identity , but still i am getting this error
Msg 1077, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ShaniProc, Line 21
INSERT into an identity column not allowed on table variables.

Comment: @Malik Why would you get an error about inserting into an `IDENTITY` column if you removed it?

Comment: I don't know that's what the problem is

Comment: @Malik Then please post your current query, because I hardly believe that you can get an error like that without an `IDENTITY` column

Comment: I have edited the question and now i have added the latest code

Comment: @Malik But, but, but you still have `active_id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY` in your table definition. **Remove the `IDENTITY`**

Comment: Awww, thanks Lamak... Its save my life but  i am not able to see the print message on the console, :(

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ShaniProc
AS
DECLARE @Driver nvarchar(20)



DECLARE @active_surveys TABLE
    (
    active_id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ani varchar,
    callDisposition int,
    CallTypeID int,
    DateTIme datetime,
    DbDateTime datetime,
    TalkTime int,
    DNIS varchar(32),
    Duration int,
    PerpheralID smallint,
    RecoveryKey float

    )
SET IDENTITY_INSERT active_surveys On

Insert into @active_surveys (active_id,ani,callDisposition,CallTypeID,DateTime,DbDateTime,TalkTime,DNIS,Duration,PerpheralID,RecoveryKey )
Select t.AgentSkillTargetID,t.ANI,t.CallDisposition,t.CallTypeID,t.DateTime,t.DbDateTime,t.TalkTime,
t.DNIS,t.Duration,t.PeripheralID,t.RecoveryKey from TCD t

SET IDENTITY_INSERT active_surveys OFF
Declare @total int;
Select @total=COUNT(*) from @active_surveys;
print '>> Total Surveys: '+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),@total),'')

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your insert statement to

```
INSERT INTO @active_surveys (
    active_id
    , ani
    , callDisposition
    , CallTypeID
    , DATETIME
    , DbDateTime
    , TalkTime
    , DNIS
    , Duration
    , PerpheralID
    , RecoveryKey
    )

    SELECT t.AgentSkillTargetID
    , t.ANI
    , t.CallDisposition
    , t.CallTypeID
    , t.DATETIME
    , t.DbDateTime
    , t.TalkTime
    , t.DNIS
    , t.Duration
    , t.PeripheralID
    , t.RecoveryKey FROM TCD t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ShaniProc
AS
DECLARE @Driver nvarchar(20)



DECLARE @active_surveys TABLE
    (
    active_id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ani varchar,
    callDisposition int,
    CallTypeID int,
    DateTIme datetime,
    DbDateTime datetime,
    TalkTime int,
    DNIS varchar(32),
    Duration int,
    PerpheralID smallint,
    RecoveryKey float

    )
SET IDENTITY_INSERT active_surveys On

Insert into @active_surveys (active_id,ani,callDisposition,CallTypeID,DateTime,DbDateTime,TalkTime,DNIS,Duration,PerpheralID,RecoveryKey )
Select t.AgentSkillTargetID,t.ANI,t.CallDisposition,t.CallTypeID,t.DateTime,t.DbDateTime,t.TalkTime,
t.DNIS,t.Duration,t.PeripheralID,t.RecoveryKey from TCD t;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT active_surveys OFF
Declare @total int;
Select @total=COUNT(*) from @active_surveys;
print '>> Total Surveys: '+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),@total),'')

GO
```